# open a UDP socket on python 3.5

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, udp

I'm trying to open a udp socket on python 3.5. I write a python code on python 2.7 and it works. when I moved on to python 3.5 it gives me an error , this is the python code :

```
from socket import *
import time

UDP_IP="192.168.1.26"
UDP_PORT = 6009
UDP_PORT2 = 5016

address= ('192.168.1.207' , 5454)
client_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.settimeout(1)
sock = socket (AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP , UDP_PORT))
sock2 = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM)
sock2.bind((UDP_IP , UDP_PORT2))

while (1) :

    data = "Temperature"

    client_socket.sendto(data , address)

    rec_data,addr = sock.recvfrom(2048)

    temperature = float(rec_data)

    print (temperature)

    outputON_1 = 'ON_1'

    outputOFF_1 = 'OFF_1'

    seuil_T = 25.00

    if (temperature < seuil_T) :
        client_socket.sendto(outputOFF_1, address)
    else :
        client_socket.sendto(outputON_1 , address)

##    sock.close()

    data = "humidity"

    client_socket.sendto(data , address)

    rec_data , addr =sock2.recvfrom(2048)

    humidity = float (rec_data)

    print (humidity)

    outputON_2 = "ON_2"

    outputOFF_2 = "OFF_2"

    seuil_H = 300

    if humidity < seuil_H :
        client_socket.sendto(outputOFF_2 , address)
    else:
        client_socket.sendto(outputON_2 , address)
 This is the error that I got :
```

client_socket.sendto(data , address)

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, the `sendto`, `send` and `sendall` methods on `socket` now take `bytes` objects and not `str`s. In order to fix this for your code you need to call `.encode()` your strings, e.g:

```
client_socket.sendto(outputOFF_2.encode() , address)
```

**Or** use *byte string literals* when defining them:

```
outputOFF_2 = b"OFF_2"
```

`s.encode()`, by default, will encode the string (`s`) using `utf8`. Alternate encodings can be provided as an argument, e.g: `s.encode('ascii')`.

Also bear in mind that `recv` and `recvfrom` will now also return `bytes` so you may need to `.decode()` them (same rules apply to `.decode` as `.encode`).

Answer (score 0):

you need to encode your string using

```
client_socket.sendto(bytes(data, 'utf-8') , address)
```